# Decoration borderradius of container destroyed by child container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I got this code

```
Container(
  width: 100.w,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(12.sp), topRight: Radius.circular(12.sp)), color: Colors.green),
  child: UnconstrainedBox(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.sp),
          child: Text(
            "my Text",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.sp),
          ))),
),
```

which results in this:

[image]

Now I want to have my child container with another background color taking a specific width of the parent container. I use this code (unconstrainedbox so that my width ist not 100% automatically):

```
Container(
  width: 100.w,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(12.sp), topRight: Radius.circular(12.sp)), color: Colors.green),
  child: UnconstrainedBox(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 75.w,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.sp),
          child: Text(
            "my Text",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.sp),
          ))),
),
```

which results in this:

[image]

I need the borderradius of the parent container to be dominant and not being 'destroyed' by its child. How can I achieve that? I can't just add the same decoration to the child because the width will grow dynamically and on some point it would be at almost 100% what would result in problems on the right side.

Comment: use `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` inside container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with `clipBehavior` property in Container.

Updated code:

```
Container(
  width: 100.w,
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(12.sp), topRight: Radius.circular(12.sp)), color: Colors.green),
  child: UnconstrainedBox(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 75.w,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.sp),
          child: Text(
            "my Text",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.sp),
          ))),
),
```

output:

[image]

Comment: clipBehavior would do the trick... It's amusing how we tend to forget this container property.

Answer (score 0):

Try using shape : Boxshape.circle parameter for the parent container
Else in clipbehaviour of container give clip.hardEdge so that parent container maintains its border radius.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to set the child border as parent border, without using decoration. For this, wrap your UnconstrainedBox with the ClipRRect widget and add border radius. This will cover up your problem.

Here is an example:

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(12),),
  child: UnconstrainedBox(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container(color: Colors.red, width: 75, padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Text("my Text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),))),),
```

Comment: i think it not a best practice